# How to make free enterence into phpMyAdmin without login at home laptop?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have installed phpMyAdmin-5.2.0 (english version) on my home kubuntu 20 and how to make free enterence
into it without login ?

Tha is not deb package installation, but I uploaded it as source and uploaded into :
/var/www/html/phpMyAdmin-5.2.0-english

Seems in earlier versions I could set such options in config.inc.php file, but in this installation I do not such file or something
similar like that

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that you dont want  a password ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't log into phpmyadmin using root and no password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466116/cant-log-into-phpmyadmin-using-root-and-no-password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the "Config" authentication type (see https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#config-authentication-mode and maybe the whole section at https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#using-authentication-modes).

To use it, you'll have to create your own file `config.inc.php` (which goes in the main phpMyAdmin folder, so `/var/www/html/phpMyAdmin-5.2.0-english/config.inc.php` for you).

At the least, you'll need the following:

```
<?php

$i=0;
$i++;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'isaac';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'mypasswordisunguessable';
```

You can adjust the user and password for ones that match your system, and note that if you use username root with a blank password, you'll need to enable [$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_AllowNoPassword).

Also note that this opens up your phpMyAdmin to anyone who can reach your machine, so you should have a firewall or routing configured to not allow external traffic from the internet to reach your server (and be aware of the LAN traffic as well, if there are others who have access to your LAN or if you have wifi available, etc). The usual disclaimers about not giving away too much access.

Mostly the authentication hasn't changed in many versions, perhaps you were expecting a `config.inc.php` file to be provided but that is not the case. You can create your own from scratch or copy the `config.sample.inc.php` file.

Comment: As I create new file config.inc.php with 4 lines you proposed, my phpMyAdmin have only header visible. Is it correct? This file has no $i defined...

Comment: Whoops, I have corrected my code. You're correct, $i should be 1 for the first server. It should go a little better now.